# Why do we use different variables(i, j) for accessing different string elements?

Tags: c, string

I can't understand why we need to use different variables such as `i`, `j` to access elements of two different strings. For example while copying characters from one string to another:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
p[j]=s[i];
}
```

Why can't we just use `p[i]` instead of say `p[j]` as shown in the above code? Why does it not work? Why do we need a separate variable `j` to access the elements of the second string and not use the same `i`?
Apologise if the question is too silly.

Comment: Because you have bugs?

Comment: When these strings are of different lengths, you may get a segfault while indexing them

Comment: That's like getting in a car, crashing it into a tree and then asking: "why can't we drive cars normally? Why do we have to drive them into trees?" We have no idea what made you or someone else write this code. Also note that using `strlen` as a loop terminating condition is dangerous as it will most likely result in the function being called after every iteration, which might slow your program down significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that looks wrong. It should indeed be

```
p[i]=s[i];
```

If that is not working, there must be something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question would be, it depends on the situation.

Lets take 2 examples.

strint `hello` has to be copied from one array to another. Then you have to use `i` for both the arrays.

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
    p[i]=s[i];
}
```

---

But, lets suppose you want to copy a portion of a string only. Suppose from `hello` you want to copy only the `llo` part. To hold the `llo` part, the new string has to be just 3 `char` long. And the string `llo` will be stored from the index `0` in the new string. But in the older string `hello` it is from index `2`. For this reason you would need 2 variables. The code for this would be

```
int j = 0;
for(i=2;i<strlen(s);i++, j++){
    p[j]=s[i];
}
```

---

Another one which i can think of is, if you just want to pick up specific characters from a string.

Just like this, there can be several situations in which you would use two different variables.